# Reset USB port on Mac

Tags: macos, terminal, usb

I occasionally need to unplug and then re-plugin my usb TV tuner, or I could restart the entire computer... seems to be the only way to get it working again.  I'm thinking that a power reset would suffice.  So my question is:

Is there any way to reset the USB port on a Mac or reset the power to the USB port through Terminal or another programatic means?

Comment: This could help https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/295993/how-to-restart-usb-subsystem/296624#296624

Comment: Try https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/240250/reset-usb-bus-without-reboot-macbook-ignores-display